# File outside of web directory is corrupt or truncated

Tags: php

I am trying to use a handler to serve a file that is outside of my web directory and I am having some issues. I want to do checks in the handler and need to be able to run a query but as soon as I add a line of code other than what I have shown, I get the error **The image “http://localhost/xampp/site_name/image_handler.php?ID=d5xa24tdufoseg868r66yjz5sr19u41i” cannot be displayed because it contains errors**. In firefox I checked the console in firebug and it says image is corrupt or truncated. However if I leave the base code I have shown it just serves the image. Anyone know why this could be?

**EDIT: Showing all code**

```
<?php
include("roc/include/connection.php");
$db = new PDOConnectionFactory();
$conn = $db->getConnection();

//prepare for utf8 characters
$sql = 'SET NAMES utf8';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$result=$stmt->execute();

$sql = 'SET CHARACTER SET utf8';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$result=$stmt->execute();
//**************************

if (! preg_match("/^[-a-z.-@,'s]*$/i",$_GET['ID']))

{

die('No illegal characters');

}

else

$empty=strlen($_GET['ID']);

if ($empty==0)

{

die('The text field cannot be empty');

}

else

{

$ID = $_GET['ID'];



if (strlen($_GET['ID'])>35){
exit("error");
}

}


$sql="SELECT file_name FROM video WHERE vid_id=?";
$stmt=$conn->prepare($sql);
$result=$stmt->execute(array($ID));

while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
$file_name = $row['file_name']."[img-004].jpg";
}

echo $path="/home/g/Desktop/processed/".$file_name."";


//check if image is readible and type
if (is_readable($path)) {

header('Content-Length: '.filesize($path)); // provide file size

header("Expires: -1");

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
$content=file_get_contents('/home/g/Desktop/processed/986861d331e8b4b4eacee5cb7aed494a[img-004].jpg');


}
else {
error_log("Can't serve image: $file_name");
}

?>
```

**HTML OUTPUT**

```
<img src="http://localhost/xampp/site_name/image_handler.php?ID=d5xa24tdufoseg868r66yjz5sr19u41i" alt="The image “http://localhost/xampp/site_name/image_handler.php?ID=d5xa24tdufoseg868r66yjz5sr19u41i” cannot be displayed because it contains errors.">
```

Comment: So... what you're saying is that the right code works right, and the wrong code works wrong?

Comment: No what I am saying that this code works but I need friggin checks. I need to be able to run queries and have more code than this buddy. This script is useless. Come on...

Comment: This code is fine. The problem is with the rest of it.

Comment: Don't forget to add the actual output as seen by the browser.

Comment: That's the HTML, not the output from the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do a `echo "test"` prior to sending headers... things will go wrong.

If you send an `echo "test"` and your headers say that you're sending an image... things will go wrong.

**Code is working.**

Comment: @Scarface, as expected. This were only not ok on your head! ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you add any additional data to image data your image will get corrupt. If you are outputting an image you better not to echo anything other than the image. The only way around might be writing whatever you want to write on the image. You can use GD functions to do that. There is another way that I might advice not to, you may add whatever you like to end of the image without getting an error. But thats not guaranteed.

PS: You can still run more code than that apart from echo'ing on the screen.

Comment: I can't even run a mysql query though. How can I run the rest of my handler without affecting the image data?

Comment: @scarface: You might have an error or something that tries to write something on the screen. First remove echo $content; part and load the file in a browser page. This should give you some info. And also make sure you start with <?php and end with ?> no white space outside the tags.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the code you are adding to do your 'checks' but as per the manual: *Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines 
in a file, or from PHP.*

Maybe you would be better off [putting that image in a buffer](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php):

```
<?php
  // Code that checks out whatever ..

  // more checks
  ob_start();
  myClass::renderPng(); //header("Content-Type: image/png"); in here
  $pngString = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you want your script to output if there is an error? HTML? A special error image?

```
<?php
$content = readfile('/home/g/Desktop/processed/986861d331e8b4b4eacee5cb7aed494a[img-004].jpg');

// Did readfile succeed?

// Do db query.

// Do some other checks.

// Now output something to browser.
if ($are_we_okay == true) {
  header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
  echo $content;
} else {
  header("Content-type: text/html");
  echo "<b>Failed!</b>";
}
?>
```

Comment: No I was just getting an error when trying to output the image, it is fixed now though.